# How compute cartesian coordination given the intrinsic and distortion matrices

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I have made a camera calibration and I have obtained the matices:
Here the intrinsic:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<Intrinsics type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>3</rows>
  <cols>3</cols>
  <dt>f</dt>
  <data>
    6.59121826e+002 0. 2.09667786e+002 0. 6.98561340e+002
    1.49071167e+002 0. 0. 1.</data></Intrinsics>
</opencv_storage>
```

And here the distortion one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<Distortion type_id="opencv-matrix">
  <rows>4</rows>
  <cols>1</cols>
  <dt>f</dt>
  <data>
    1.11172847e-001 -1.00810878e-001 -1.00857615e-001 -8.45640600e-002</data></Distortion>
</opencv_storage>
```

After such a process, I am supposed to find for a point `A(u,v)` in image plane its coordination in my cartesian referee `R(X,Y,Z)`.

Note: The `Z` axis is parallel to optical axis, `X` axis is also parallel to `u` axis and so on for `Y` and `v`.

I followed [this online turorial](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/OWENS/LECT9/node2.html) but I couldn't compute `X`, `Y` and `Z`.

Any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is it possible to obtain 3D coordinates from 2D projection?

Comment: I am still waiting for answer plz

Answer (score 1):

If intrinsic matrix is `K` and distortion operator is `D`, then for a given point `A(u,v)`, the corresponding point in space will be `(X,Y,Z)^T = t * D^-1 * K^-1 * (u,v,1)^T`, where `t > 0` is an arbitrary real number. It is assumed that camera center is located in the origin.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean by D the only vector I mentioned?
My camera center is not in the origin but I should make referees transformation after computing.

Comment: If the vector k (you mentioned) is distortion coefficients used in OpenCV, then `D^-1 * (x,y,1)^T = (x*(1 + k1*(x^2+y^2) + k2*(x^2+y^2)^2, y*(1 + k1*(x^2+y^2) + k2*(x^2+y^2)^2, 1)` (only radial distortion is corrected here). See this page for more information: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html